# Weird arithmetic precision in ocaml

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I have fount weird problem in arithmetic precision in OCaml. Look:

```
# 1.1+.2.2;;
 - : float = 3.30000000000000027
```

It happen only when I do: something.1 + something.2. Could someone try it?

Comment: That's not weird, that's intrinsic to floating point numbers. You're the 1000th (ballpark) user to stumble upon this.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reality of using floating-point values. While 1.1 is represented exactly in decimal with two digits, it takes an infinite number of binary digits to represent this value. Since you are are storing 1.1 in binary with a finite number of bits, rounding error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Ocaml float numbers are [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision numbers. You'll have the same behavior in other programming languages. Perhaps you want floating [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) (which Ocaml don't provide).

A computer has always finite precision native numbers (much like a calculator).